# Check if a command in bash has output the right dynamic value and string

Tags: linux, bash, grep, command, output

I'm trying to make a bash script that checks if a specific command has outputted the expected result. The output should be 
`N user(s)` has been exported in the output file.

How should I check it if `N` is a dynamic value in number

I used this code to check but this will only check a specific string:

```
./command.sh -e | grep 'string' &> /dev/null
    if [ $? == 0 ]; then
       echo "PASS" 
    fi
```

Comment: Where is the parameter N determined? Inside command.sh ?

Comment: yes, it N is the number of users exported to files, i am thinking of using regex in grep

Comment: I don't understand if you want to check if N has the good value inside output "N user(s)" or if you want to check if output contain "N user(s)" with N a dynamic number but whose value does not matter to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following **grep** command will only grep the numeric result from the output: `N user(s)`:

```
grep -oP '^[0-9]+'
```

Example:

```
echo '1 user(s)' | grep -oP '^[0-9]+'
```

Output:

```
1
```

---

```
echo '100 user(s)' | grep -oP '^[0-9]+'
```

Output:

```
100
```

Note that the output should be `N user(s)`, will you have other cases that could break this regex ?

Update:

In order to check for the whole output you can use this one:

```
echo '1 user(s) has been exported in the output file' | grep -P '^[0-9]+\suser\(s\)\shas\sbeen\sexported\sin\sthe\soutput\sfile'
```

OR

```
echo '1 user(s) has been exported in the output file' | grep -P '^[0-9]+\suser\(s\)\s(\w|\s)+'
```

OR

```
echo '1 user(s) has been exported in the output file' | grep -P '^[0-9]+\s\w+\(\w\)(\s|\w)+'
```

Output:

```
1 user(s) has been exported in the output file
```

Comment: Hi thank you! this one works! how ever i used this command instead
grep "[0-9]* has been exported in the output file"

Comment: you are welcome!, if this answer was helpful don't forget to mark your question as answered.